# Meteor: how to point native mobile app to deployed server

Tags: android, ios, node.js, meteor, native

If you have a meteor app hosted on modulus that is a web and native mobile app, how do you point the native app towards meteor's backend. Also, does meteor still 'send down' the front-end when it is accessed for a native app?

Comment: Have you tried the [--server option](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#building) of `meteor build`?

Comment: I have tried both `meteor build --server my-app.meteor.com` and `meteor run ios-device --mobile-server my-app.meteor.com` and neither are working. But I'm also using this repo (https://github.com/Compy/meteor-mobile-desktop) as a template - so the package structure may be messing me up. I'll post an answer if I figure out the source of my pain.

Answer (score 0):

Use iron router and create an API with Meteor. Then in the native app just send requests to the API.

Here is an example of an api created using iron router:
https://github.com/awatson1978/rest-api

Read more on making an API with meteor:
http://meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API

Answer (score 0):

Check out the meteor docu @ https://www.meteor.com/try/7 
meteor run android-device --mobile-server my_app_name.meteor.com